# Python create list from smallest number of repeating values in a nested list

Tags: python

I have a Dict

```
whs = {
    'ID1' : ['code1', 'code2', 'code3'],
    'ID2' : ['code2', 'code5', 'code3'],
    'ID3' : ['code6', 'code7', 'code8'],
    'ID4' : ['code3', 'code5', 'code6'],
}
```

What I need to do is build a new list that will look like

```
submit = [
    {
        'codes' : ['code3', ],
        'ids' : ['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID4'],
    },
    {
        'codes' : ['code6', 'code7', 'code8'],
        'ids' : ['ID3', ],
    }
]
```

What I have so far

```
def ParseAvailable(self, whs):
    separate = whs.keys()
    submit = []
    while len(separate) > 0:
        avail = {
            'codes' : [],
            'ids' : [],
        }
        for num, item in enumerate(separate):
            if len(avail['codes']) == 0:
                avail['codes'] = whs[item]
                avail['ids'].append(item)
            else:
                avail_all = list(set(avail['codes']) & set(whs[item]))
                print '%s : %s' % (item, avail_all)
                if len(avail_all) > 0:
                    avail['codes'] = avail_all
                    avail['ids'].append(item)
            if len(avail['codes']) > 0:
                del separate[num]
        submit.append(avail)
    return submit
```

Which returns:

```
[
    {
        'ids': ['ID4', 'ID3'], 
        'codes': ['code6']
    },
    {
        'ids': ['ID2'], 
        'codes': ['code2', 'code5', 'code3']
    },
    {
        'ids': ['ID1'],
         'codes': ['code1', 'code2', 'code3']
    }
]
```

which COULD work except that ID1 & ID2 should be combined as

```
{
    'ids' : ['ID1', 'ID2',],
    'codes' : ['code2', 'code3', ]
}
```

Curious if there is an easier approach that I've not thought of, figure I could setup a couple more nested loops to compare everything piece by piece though it seems rather unpythonic

Thank You in Advance

Comment: The structure of your output seems odd.  What exactly are you looking for in the output? What rules define it's structure?

Comment: the end goal is to take a list of products (IDS) that are available from different warehouses (codes) and create an order list from a minimum number of warehouses -- this portion sorts through before being parsed into an XML submission query -- this structure seemed the simplest way to pass the data between functions -- though I'm open to suggestions

Comment: In your example, you don't include every code in the output.  Is there another list of the codes which must be included? Or did you summarize the output?

Comment: FYI, it appears your problem is an instance of set cover, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem , which is going to be "hard" so hopefully you don't have large data sets.

Comment: The function you are looking for builds indices over your data. This screams for a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I attacked it by building a tree of all the potential additions, and then finding the cheapest option among those.  Here is a working (albeit ugly and unoptimized) example:

https://gist.github.com/1288835

The tree will end up with p*w nodes, where p is the number of products and w(p) is the average number of warehouses per product.

Comment: If the data size is non-trivial you will want to add pruning so that branches of the tree are not enumerated once a shorter answer has already been found.

Comment: As mentioned probably not the best solution for a very large dataset. Luckily the sets this app will be working with at any time should remain rather small. Many thanks for posting working code - found myself learning a bit from your approach.

Comment: @ZackBloom I was more concerned about pruning during `build tree`

Comment: @goldsz Ah, fair point.  You could make it more performant by integrating the tree building and path finding.

Comment: revisiting this function I found it wasn't quite was I was looking for - this version returns a dict with ID as the key and a list of codes as var -- trick is that each addition overwrites the existing ID so it  only returns the last ID

Comment: @Alvin When I run it with your example data (the data in the gist), I get: (3, defaultdict(<type 'set'>, {'ID4': set(['code3', 'code5', 'code6']), 'ID3': set(['code8', 'code7']), 'ID1': set(['code1', 'code2'])}))

Answer (score 0):

So it looks to me like you have a [set cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) problem, which is NP-complete. Not only that, but it appears that you want all the possible set covers of the minimum size. Your list of ids creates the universe set, and each of your codes creates a sub set of the universe.

For your simple iterative loops you don't really have a choice other then to try all possible combinations of codes. If you have large data sets this isn't going to work.

The wikipedia article mentions an efficient algorithm (greedy algorithm) that isn't guaranteed to find the best solution, but the error in the solution is bounded. This algorithm is to iteratively add the subset the contains the most uncovered elements of the universe.

If you need to get the absolutely correct answer you may want to try the Integer Programming approach (as in Linear Programming). There are software packages and libraries for this algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

As others said, this is an optimization problem that isn't trivial for large datasets.  But as a first step, it's at least easy to invert the list of warehouses per product to a list of products per warehouse.

```
whs = {
    'ID1' : ['code1', 'code2', 'code3'],
    'ID2' : ['code2', 'code5', 'code3'],
    'ID3' : ['code6', 'code7', 'code8'],
    'ID4' : ['code3', 'code5', 'code6'],
}

a = []
b = []
for k,v in whs.items():
    for j in v:
        a.append((j,k))
        b.append((j,[]))
inv = dict(b)
for j in a:
    inv[j[0]].append(j[1])

print("Inventory:")
for k,v in inv.items():
    print(k,v)
```

When run, this prints:

```
Inventory:
code1 ['ID1']
code2 ['ID2', 'ID1']
code3 ['ID4', 'ID2', 'ID1']
code5 ['ID4', 'ID2']
code6 ['ID4', 'ID3']
code7 ['ID3']
code8 ['ID3']
```

As you can see from the trivial example, there are no solutions that will get all products in a single order, and several solutions (code2+code6, code3+code6, code3+code7, code3+code8) that will get them in two orders.  Picking the "best" would require additional information, such as pricing, to optimize on.

Comment: the idea is to run the result through another process that will determine the closest warehouse when len("codes") > 0